# how can we restore multiple databases that are dependent in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have multiple databases in `sql server 2008` that have dependencies to each other (databases are dependent) how can i restore these multiple databases at once.

Please help.

Thanx in advance

Comment: This would be a good question for http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Specified "sql server 2008" in question , so removed mysql, oracle tag